# What is the preferred way to typeset hyphens in scientific terminology credited to multiple people?

Tags: typography

Gouy-Chapman theory is a scientific theory devised by Gouy and Chapman. Similarly, Brunauer-Emmett-Teller is a theory devised by ... Brunauer, Emmett, and Teller.  How should I typeset these?

I realize this is more of a style/typography question, but I would be very grateful if you would provide your help and/or opinions on this. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\usepackage[font={sf,small},labelsep=quad,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\noindent
(a) Gouy-Chapman theory\\
(b) Gouy--Chapman theory\\

\noindent
(a) Brunauer-Emmett-Teller theory\\
(b) Brunauer--Emmett--Teller theory

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 1):

If we write it with a hyphen, it means one person with a compound name, e.g. Ryll-Nardzewski or Skłodowska-Curie. En-dash (obtained by two hyphens) means two (or more) people, as `Gouy--Chapman` theory,